# Public function smart contract Clarity Stacks

Tags: stack, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

I am writing a public function that only owner of the contract can call.
It is a funciton that changes a state variable in a smart conract.

```
(define-public (changeRatio (newRatio uint))
  (begin
    (asserts! (is-eq tx-sender (var-get contract-owner)) ERR-NOT-AUTHORIZED)
    (var-set ratio newRatio)
  )
)
```

and I get

error: detected two execution paths, returning two different expression types (got '(response UnknownType uint)' and 'bool')

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Public functions in Clarity have to return a response type at the end. See the Clarity book for more info on this: https://book.clarity-lang.org/ch05-01-public-functions.html

To solve your particular error, you could wrap your `var-set` in an `ok` response type like this:

`(ok (var-set ratio newRatio))`

Note that this will only work if your `ERR-NOT-AUTHORIZED` is an `err` and not just a `uint`, since `err` and `ok` are both response types.